# p2p/NodeJS: Undocumented code does not tell us how to send messages through the network

Tags: javascript, node.js, messaging, p2p

We are at a standstill with a dead repository and would like to bring it back to life. Our only problem is, it's lacks so much documentation, it's almost unusable.

We are able to make a connection to the network, show when people connect, disconnect, and who all is online.

[Here is the repo in question.](https://github.com/patr0nus/n2n) The file to keep an eye on is /lib/node.js (not to be confused with NodeJS itself).

Here is what we have to show for it:

```
var Node = require('n2n').Node;
var node = new Node(5146);

console.log("Connecting to the network...\n\n\n");
node.connect([{ host: 'bradleypl.us', port: 5146 }]);

node.on('online', function () {
  console.log('Your ID:', this.id);
  console.log('Online ids:', node.sortedIds);
});

//just for testing, this will spam the terminal if repeated every time.
node.on('node::online', function (newNode) {
  console.log('Someone is online:', newNode.id);
});

//just for testing, this will spam the terminal if repeated every time.
node.on('node::offline', function () {
  console.log('Someone just left!');
});
```

This is where we have no idea what to so. Now how does one send messages? We can see something like:

```
node.broadcast("node::test","message");
```

Being used to send a "node::test" event to everyone on the network. That is then received with:

```
node.on("node::test", function (message) {
  console.log("New message:",message);
}
```

But that doesn't work... Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears from a brief look at the code that you should be doing this:

node.send("test",  "message")

Also there's not much there...you may be better off just rewriting what you need instead of trying to make sense of an undocumented small lib. Just my 2 cents.

Comment: I think that's a good advice. I have had a look at the code too and also tried to get it running locally but it wasn't working. Then I have checked [Socket.io chat example](http://socket.io/get-started/chat/) and that was running instantly. I modified the code a bit to have it run with a MEAN stack and it's already communicating between browser tabs. (It's a bit hacky at the moment, everything in the main controller, no persistence, no user management, but it works.)

Comment: Sorry for responding 5 years later. I did end up just rewriting my own solution with Sockets like @AWolf did. I accepted the answer because using the library was way more painful than just using another solution.

Answer (score 0):

Someone helped me find the solution, it appears that it emits 2 arguments when sending messages.

```
//node::eventName, function handles senderID and data
node.on("node::test", function (sentFrom, message) {
  console.log("New message:",message);
}
```

Also, to send a message, you must use:

```
// userID, eventName, data (in this case, a string)
node.send("userid-342trw-tq34t3w-44q3t","test","Hello, World!");
```